# Create and build docker Dockerfile from a script

Tags: python, linux, docker

I am having some difficulty trying to create a script which creates and builds a docker file that gets the current users uid and gid and sets the user vagrant's uid and gid inside of container to match the host.

```
output = "FROM %s\nUSER root\nRUN usermod --uid %s vagrant && groupmod --gid %s vagrant && chown -R vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant\nUSER vagrant" % (build_image, uid, gid)
f = open("Dockerfile", "w")
f.write(output)
f.close

# Build the image using the created Dockerfile
build_command = "docker build -t %s . --pull" % args.name
print("\nRunning: " + build_command)
subprocess.call(['bash', '-c', build_command])
```

`docker build -t test-image . --pull` works on the command line but when running the script I get: "Error response from daemon: the Dockerfile (Dockerfile) cannot be empty"

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: As an aside, passing a string to `['bash', '-c', cmd]` is just a roundabout way of reimplementing `cmd, shell=True`. You want to avoid both; pass `['docker', 'build', '-t', args.name, '.', '--pull']` directly.

Comment: Are you maybe in a different working directory on the Command Line compared to the script?

Comment: @tripleee Thanks that's good to know, I will get that changed

Comment: @Bernhard No it is all inside of the same directory

Comment: Is the file created and does it contain what you're expecting?

Comment: @oblio yeah it does, turns out I wasn't closing the file properly the answer below solved the issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually calling `f.close`; the result of that line is the uncalled close function itself.  A better approach to file handling in Python in general is to use context manager "with" syntax:

```py
with open("Dockerfile", "w") as f:
  f.write(output)
```

and then the file will be closed for you.

(Actual writes are somewhat expensive, and so Python, like most other languages, will actually keep content to be written in an in-memory buffer until the file is closed, explicitly flushed, or more than a certain amount of content is written, which is why not actually calling `f.close()` causes a problem.)

Comment: while I agree that the context manager is nicer here: there is an `f.close` in the code shown? Should it be `f.close()`?

Comment: Thank you this solved the issues, I am still new to python thanks for the clear explanation.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be `f.close()` as written.